# Laravel package trait not found

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm developing a package and added a "Traits" dir to my PSR-4 structure and this is reflected in the package's composer.json.

```
{
    "name": "my-private-repo/prefs",
    "description": "Preferences package.",
    "type": "package",
    "keywords": [
        "prefs",
        "preferences"
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "illuminate/support": "5.2.*",
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*",
        "anahkiasen/former": "~4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "src/controllers",
            "src/models"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "MyPrivateRepo\\Prefs\\": "src/"
        },
        "files": [
            "src/Prefs/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Within the `src/` dir is this structure:

```
Prefs/
    Traits/
        HasPrefs.php
    Prefs.php
    PrefsServiceProvider.php
    helpers.php
```

Here is the contents of `HasPrefs.php`:

```
namespace MyPrivateRepo\Prefs\Traits;

use MyPrivateRepo\Prefs\Prefs;

trait HasPrefs
{
    public function prefs($key = null, $value = null)
    {
        //...do pref related stuff here...
    }
}
```

I've loaded the private project up and everything was working great when calling the `Prefs` class directly. Then I decided to test adding `HasPrefs` trait to my `User` model:

```
namespace App;

use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Users\EloquentUser;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;
use MyPrivateRepo\Prefs\Traits\HasPrefs;

class User extends EloquentUser implements
    AuthenticatableContract,
    AuthorizableContract,
    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use SoftDeletes,
        Authenticatable,
        Authorizable,
        HasPrefs,
        CanResetPassword;

    //...do lots of user related stuff here...
}
```

Now, every time I try to do anything, I'm given this error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Trait 'MyPrivateRepo\Prefs\Traits\HasPrefs' not found
```

I then did `composer update` but got the same error as above when it reaches the scripts section that runs `php artisan optimize`.

I commented out the references to `HasPrefs` in `User` and re-ran `artisan optimize` which worked without issue.

Uncommented `HasPrefs` and all is working as expected with no errors...until the next time I need to run `composer update` again on the project. Then, I am right back to having to comment out references to `HasPrefs` again and manually run `artisan optimize`.

Given that this is something that needs to be deployed to a production server, I can't be manually editing every file that uses this trait every time there is a `composer update` or `composer install` triggered by an auto-deploy.

I've tried the following to resolve this to no success:

- artisan clear-cache
- composer self-update
- composer clear && composer update -o
- After commenting out HasPrefs again: artisan clear-compiled && artisan optimize
- rm composer.lock && composer update -o
- rm -rf vendor/* && composer install

All it takes is a single call to `composer update` to break it all over again if any of the above temporarily fixed the issue.

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see here:

```
"psr-4": {
    "MyPrivateRepo\\Prefs\\": "src/"
},
```

You point `src` dir as `MyPrivateRepo\Prefs` namespace. So when you want to use this trait in the dir named `Traits` your namespace should go like:

```
MyPrivateRepo\Prefs\Prefs\Traits
```

because you have a `Prefs` also, so your `use` statement in this trait will looks like:

```
 use MyPrivateRepo\Prefs\Prefs\Prefs;
```

My advice is to change the composer's entry for:

```
"psr-4": {
    "MyPrivateRepo\\": "src/"
},
```

Comment: The problem I run into with just doing `"MyPrivateRepo\\": "src/"` is that there are multiple other packages from this same private repo. All of these other packages have the same sort of PSR-4 declaration. For instance, I also have another composer.json that has `"MyPrivateRepo\\SDK\\": "src/"`.

Comment: If you want to use two composer you shouldn't using them on one `src`. Try to split it to other package into anathor directory for example: `MyPrivateRepo/Sdk/src/...` and `MyPrivateRepo/Prefs/src/...`.

Comment: Greate , so you can drop the `Prefs` director from inside of `src` (so all the dirs grom it will be inside the `src` directly). You have to understand `PSR-4`, it works that way.

Comment: They are in different directories, but under the same parent `my-private-repo` vendor dir. For instance, `"MyPrivateRepo\\Prefs\\": "src/"` corresponds to `vendor/my-private-repo/prefs/src` and `"MyPrivateRepo\\SDK\\": "src/"` corresponds to `vendor/my-private-repo/sdk/src`.

Comment: Gotcha. Will give it a try! (FYI, accidentally deleted previous comment when I meant to edit.)

Comment: Tried changing `"MyPrivateRepo\\Prefs\\": "src/"` to `"MyPrivateRepo\\": "src/"` but I still get the same "trait not found error" after each new `composer update` when it gets to `artisan optimize`. If I change references to `use MyPrivateRepo\Prefs\Prefs\Traits\HasPrefs` I get a `Trait 'MyPrivateRepo\Prefs\Prefs\Traits\HasPrefs' not found` error (PHPStorm also immediately complains about class not found as well).

Comment: If you set: `"MyPrivateRepo\\": "src/"` then: `use MyPrivateRepo\Prefs\Traits\HasPrefs` should work without one `Prefs`. With PSR-4 you don't need to `artisan optimize`. Try `composer dump`.

Comment: Tried this. If I do exactly that and do `composer dump`, then I get the same error as before. If I comment everything out and run `artisan optimize` then uncomment, everything works again. The moment I run `composer dump` after that, the trait can't be found anymore.

Comment: Tried deleting the vendor dir entirely and re-installed everything with the new PSR-4 suggestion changes....and it worked this time! :D